# undefined method `use_transactional_tests=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007fccf515e338> (NoMethodError)

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm testing the new Rails version `5.0.0.alpha` and RSpec `3.1.7` but I'm receiving the error:

```
undefined method `use_transactional_tests=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007fccf515e338> (NoMethodError)
```

In `rails_helper.rb` I usually use this and all works fine:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

But I received this warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: use_transactional_fixtures= is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.0 (use use_transactional_tests= instead). (called from block in <module:FixtureSupport> at /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-rails-3.1.0/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb:25)
```

So, I changed my `rails_helper.rb` to use the new way:

```
config.use_transactional_tests = true
```

And now I received this error:

```
/Users/monteirobrena/project/spec/rails_helper.rb:34:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `use_transactional_tests=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007fccf515e338> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core.rb:81:in `configure'
from /Users/monteirobrena/project/spec/rails_helper.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/monteirobrena/project/spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/monteirobrena/project/spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deprecation warning and suggestion you are getting is from Rails, not RSpec or the rspec-rails gem. The rspec-rails gem implements `use_transactional_fixtures=` [and turns around and calls the same method in Rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/a6bdb463d7676d4160d3881a4605d3362d210a74/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb#L25). It does not implement `use_transactional_tests=`, so you're getting that error message when you made that change.

Unless the rspec-rails gem is upgraded to support the new Rails 5 features, you'll need to set the Rails configuration directly - and as of rspec-rails 3.8 it does not.

Comment: Can you explaing which lines I need to delete and which lines I need to add in this case?

Comment: For those finding this post in 2018: I am upgrading a Rails 4 Engine to Rails 5.1 and to solve this error I replaced all occurrences of "use_transactional_fixtures"  to "use_transactional_tests". Except within /spec/rails_helper.rb which still needed "use_transactional_fixtures". RSpec tests now run successfully.

Comment: rspec 3.8 and in 2019 - the most recent advice remains the same - with rspec "use_transactional_fixtures"

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep using **config.use_transactional_fixtures = true** in rspec configure for **rails 5 beta** (at least till the official release, not sure what are the rspec team plans on supporting this).
The fix is already on master branch, [here is the line fixing it.](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/a6bdb463d7676d4160d3881a4605d3362d210a74/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb#L25)

Set the rspec gems on master branch:

```
%w[rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks rspec-rails rspec-support].each do |lib|
    gem lib, git: "https://github.com/rspec/#{lib}.git", branch: 'master'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated my rspec version, so I didn't have the need to change my `use_transactional_fixtures` line. In the meantime there's just a beta version:

```
gem 'rspec', '~> 3.5.0.beta4'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5.0.beta4'
```